# Reset the function variable back to default after successful submit to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

With jQuery, I have a button that adds input fields on click with unique `id` and `name` for each field which is determined by a function and counter variable `var count = 0;`. How can I reset the counter after submitting the form to the database, so that the `id` and `name` of the input fields starts from the default again without refreshing the page?

Here is a snippet of the form:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
        var count = 0;

        $('p#add_field').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            count += 1;
            $('#container').append(
                '<div>\n\
                   <label>Weight</label><input type="text" id="weight_' + count + '" name="weight[]' + '"/>\n\
                <a href="#" class="remove_field" id="removebtn">Remove</a><br>'
            );
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="productForm">
   <div id="container" class="input_fields_wrap">
      <div>
         <p id="add_field"><button type="button" href="#"><span>Add new</span></button></p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit">Save to database</button>
</form>
```

Here is what I have been working with to remove the dynamic elements after successful submit. (Am I doing this in right way?) Now how can I reset the `var count` back to `= 0` here? Thanks in advance.

```
$.ajax({
      url: form.attr('action'),
      type: form.attr('method'),
      data: form.serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {

          if (response.success == true) {
            $("[id*='weight']").each(function() {
              $(this).parent("div").remove();
            });

            $("[id*='removebtn']").each(function() {
              $(this).parent("div").remove();
            });
```

Comment: count=0 should work... Just make sure it's available in the scope

Comment: `$("#container").children().next().remove()` would be simpler than what you're doing currently to remove them. but... i would argue you don't even need the `count` var or the id's.

Comment: If they really need to be enumerated, you can do that while you're submitting the form and thus have no count var that needs to be reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will look like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
        var count = 0;

        $('p#add_field').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            count += 1;
            $('#container').append(
                '<div>\n\
                   <label>Weight</label><input type="text" id="weight_' + count + '" name="weight[]' + '"/>\n\
                <a href="#" class="remove_field" id="removebtn">Remove</a><br>'
            );
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
       })
//Send data to database  on a click of a button

$('#sendDataTodb').click( function(){
$.ajax({
      url: form.attr('action'),
      type: form.attr('method'),
      data: form.serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {

          if (response.success == true) {
            $("[id*='weight']").each(function() {
              $(this).parent("div").remove();
            });

            $("[id*='removebtn']").each(function() {
              $(this).parent("div").remove();
                });
}
});
    //reset counter
    count =0;
    });

    });
```